# LWP read fail error

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I am using LWP::UserAgent to do a simple HTTP Post and get the error below. After much searching online it seems that there was a bug some time back that was fixed. My version 6.03 should be fixed. Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
'_content' => 'read failed:  at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 256
 at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Net/SSL.pm line 211
        Net::SSL::die_with_error(\'LWP::Protocol::https::Socket=GLOB(0x8d9aa38)\', \'read failed\') called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1/Net/SSL.pm line 224
        Net::SSL::read(\'LWP::Protocol::https::Socket=GLOB(0x8d9aa38)\', \'\', 1024, 0) called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 256
        Net::HTTP::Methods::my_readline(\'LWP::Protocol::https::Socket=GLOB(0x8d9aa38)\', \'Status\') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 343
        Net::HTTP::Methods::read_response_headers(\'LWP::Protocol::https::Socket=GLOB(0x8d9aa38)\', \'laxed\', 1, \'junk_out\', \'ARRAY(0x8cd3d98)\') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 378
```

Here is the code sample:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;

my $response = $ua->get('https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent');
print Dumper($response);
```

Comment: Could you provide a small code example to demonstrate how to provoke the error.

Comment: When I run this code (LWP::UserAgent::VERSION 6.03) everything works.

Comment: Hmm, I checked and all dependent packages are up to date. Maybe something wrong with the box?

Comment: I found the solution by chance. I was missing IO::Socket::SSL. I found this out while trying to install Furl::HTTP, which was intelligently enough written to tell me exactly what was wrong.

Hurrah for proper error messages.

Comment: [LWP-Protocol-https requires IO::Socket::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/LWP-Protocol-https/META.yml), so this means you did not install it properly/did not perform the check for dependent packages correctly.

Comment: It was pre installed on the server I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a recent version of [IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL) the required version (1.38) is not enough (I've just installed 1.54 which seems to work fine).

https://metacpan.org/source/GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.03/Makefile.PL - this has now been released with a dependency on 1.54 - so hopefully that will sort stuff out.